# Redux reducer state is undefined at production

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have react-redux app **which works fine without error during development, but in production, It doesn't work.**

I've completely removed redux-dev-tolls etc but no chance.

I'm getting this error;

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoading' of undefined
```

I declared `signInStatus`, and `isLoading`  inside of react render function like this;

```
const {signin, signInStatus} = this.props
const {
    isLoading,
    isSucceeded,
    idErrorMessage,
    passwordErrorMessage,
    generalErrorMessage
} = signInStatus;
```

Connection;

```
const reduxInjected = connect(({signInStatus}) => ({signInStatus}), {
    signin,
    signInResetForm,
    signinStorage
})(LoginEmailPasswordForm);
....
```

Reducer;

```
const signInStatus = (state = {isLoading: false, isSucceeded: false}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // Hot Module Replacement
        case EPIC_END:
            return {isLoading: false, isSucceeded: false};

        case ...:
            return {...state, isLoading: false, isSucceeded: false};

        case ...:
        case ...:
        case ...:
            return {isLoading: true, isSucceeded: false};

        case ...:
        case ...:
            const {accessToken, idToken, expiresIn} = action;
            let expiresAt = JSON.stringify((action.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
            return {isSucceeded: true, token: {accessToken, idToken, expiresAt}};

        case ...:
            return {isSucceeded: true, isLoggedIn: true, token: action.token, user: action.user};

        case ...:
            return {}

        case ...:
            const newState = {}
            const {error} = action;
            ...
            return {...newState, isLoading: false, isSucceeded: false};

        case ...:
            return {...state, isLoggedIn: true, user: action}

        case ...:
            return {}

        default:
            return {...state}
    }
}
```

You can see signInStatus has initial state, but it says it's `undefined`

What could be the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: show us where you combine reducers / setup store

Comment: or maybe your'e not injecting provider correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about UglifyJsPlugin

```
plugins: [
    // Don't Minify JS, redux doesn't like it
    // new UglifyJsPlugin({
    //     sourceMap: true,
    //     compress: false,
    // }),
],
```